# change the coordmode from the active window to any window

Tags: autohotkey

this is the situation:

1) I have 3 Windows;

2) My mouse is positioned over any of them (active table under the mouse cursor);

3) I have the ahk_id of both Windows (stored in global variables);

4) Every 5 seconds, I would check (regardless of the movement of the mouse cursor), if a pixel of a specific window (window1, window2...) has a certain color;

5) Click with a controlclik of that pixel and regain control of the starting window under the mouse cursor.

```
checktime(){
var := Mod(A_Sec, 5)
if (var = 0){
    checkpixel(window1) ; window1 is an ahk_id, stored in a global variable
    checkpixel(window2)
    checkpixel(window3)
}

checkpixel(window){
CoordMode, ToolTip, window ; this line of code is definitely wrong, what do you recommend?
pixelgetcolor, color, 440, 295
if(color=0x4E3500){
    controlclick, x440 y295, ahk_id %window%
}
```

thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Are the windows visible at all times? If they are I'd use the `CoordMode, pixel, screen` and use the `WinGetPos` command to find out where on the screen each window is so you can calculate the position of the pixel at 440 + X, 295 + Y for your checks.

Comment: yes, the windows are always visible and your solution (coordMode, pixel, screen + wingetpos) works fine. but if a window is partially visible (and its pixels) is a problem!

Comment: To use pixelgetcolor you need to see the pixels. If the computer is unattended, you can activate each window to force it to show. If that is not an option, it all depends on why you want to do see the pixels in the first place and how the windows behave.

Comment: I'm writing a script that works on multiple windows (9+ tiled, not fully overlapped), but I can't activate each window (every 5 seconds) because isn't an elegant solution (disco lights effect!). I have to find a solution which controls the color of the pixel of a window even if it's placed under another active window :(

Comment: As a quick fix you could move all windows onto the screen in a way that the pixel can be seen and then write an AHK script that positiones all windows this way and forces them to stay this way. If I remember it correctly there is also some advanced way to get the screen of a hidden window saved into a file, you could search the autohotkey user forums for that.

Comment: ok, I'll find this solution... thanks for the answers.